# How to make better CPU utilization when running MATLAB code with loops?

Tags: matlab, performance, cpu-usage

I have a code that is time consuming to run as it contains a few `for` loops. Whether or not the code can be optimized by using vectorization is another topic. The issue is, since it was taking a long time (hours) to finish, I decided to check CPU utilization when the code was running. To my surprise, I found that it was fluctuating between 0 and 3%!

[image]

Why is the CPU not utilizing at least 25%, since my CPU is quad core (and I think each core handles 1 thread at a time, isn't it?), by default when it is not doing anything else? How do I increase the CPU utilization when running the code so that it executes faster?

In case it is relevant, here is the code (the function `xyz` in the screenshot) I am running:

```
users(:,1)=unique(M(:,10));
categories(:,1)=unique(M(:,2));
N=size(users,1);
for i=1:N
    U=M(M(:,10)==users(i,1),:);
    C(:,1)=unique(U(:,2));
    [~,~,subs] = unique(U(:,2));
    vals = U(:,9);
    C(:,2) = accumarray(subs(:), vals(:), [], @(x) 1-mean(x));
    for j=1:size(categories,1)
        for k=1:size(C,1)
            if categories(j,1)==C(k,1)
                categories(j,i)=C(k,2);
            end
        end
    end
    clear C;
end
```

Comment: It may be due to your system /OS configuration that it cannot use more than 4GB of memory and offload its task on the hard disk.

Comment: My purely speculative answer is that it _is_ using 100% of a single CPU for the actual calculation, but that the utilization _per second_ (in fact, I believe that the graph is showing CPU utilization per 6 seconds) is far lower because your calculation is being done in an unoptimized triple-nested loop, and so there is a lot of idle time between each individual calculation.

Answer (score 0):

By default matlab programs are single threaded if you want to utilize more threads you can use a `parfor` loop https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html (assuming you have the Parallel Toolbox). At a quick glance your code looks parallelizable on any of your loops, but its a bit of a balance to pick the best choice; it highly depends on the number of iterations each loop would have at runtime.

Comment: You should add here that this is only available if you have the Parallel Toolbox.